# Could not find File error in Azure Pipelines (but working in VS2019)

Tags: c#, json, azure, error-handling

I have a collection of tests in a testing project within VS where the tests manipulate a JSON file (saved within the project and Azure Repo) and then validate against that JSON File. The tests either pass or fail and then the JSON file is restored back to its original value through appending from another Success JSON File.

When I run the tests in VS2019, they all run successfully.

But when I run them in the azure pipelines, I am getting the error

```
"System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path"
```

This is the path I am calling within the VS solution (I have put ref names in to not show any company data. They are filled in the real solution

```
public const string sendProposalJSONFile = @"C:\Users\[myName]\source\repos\[SolutionName]\TestingProject\bin\Debug\JSON.json'";
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Why would you expect the path `C:\Users[myName]\source...` to exist in Azure pipelines?

Comment: It wont exist in azure, thats why I would like to know what the relative path would be